# Javax Swing Timers - Changing the delay time

Tags: java, swing

I took a learning Java program here
https://www.utdallas.edu/~dheroy/4331code/book/ImageAudioAnimation.java

I have noticed a flaw in this program

```
private int[] delays =
    {48000, 54000, 59000, 54000, 59000, 31000, 68000};
private Timer timer = new Timer(delays[0], new TimerListener());
```

The timer is initialized with the value of delays[0]  (**48000**)
Now the timer is stuck at this throughout the program. Even after we call this line of code

```
 timer.setDelay(delays[index]);
```

I am trying to rewrite this program to make it do what it's suppose to do. I am stuck on getting this timer to change from what it was initialized with. I haven't worked in Java much since 2012, so I'm a little rusty at it, especially the GUI side of it.

Should I ditch the Timer Object and come up with a another way to track elapsed time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do two things:

- Set the initial delay too, otherwise the timer will keep waiting as much as initially specified.
- Restart the timer.

You can set an exceptionally low delay like this:

```
    timer.setInitialDelay(5);
    timer.setDelay(5);
    timer.restart();
```

Comment: Thanks. I wrapped timer.setDelay() with    timer.setInitialDelay();
and timer.restart(); and that seemed to get the program to work as intended. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html):

> A Swing timer (an instance of javax.swing.Timer) fires one or more
>   action events after a specified delay. Do not confuse Swing timers
>   with the general-purpose timer facility in the java.util package. This
>   page describes only Swing timers.
>
> In general, we recommend using Swing timers rather than
>   general-purpose timers for GUI-related tasks because Swing timers all
>   share the same, pre-existing timer thread and the GUI-related task
>   automatically executes on the event-dispatch thread. However, you
>   might use a general-purpose timer if you don't plan on touching the
>   GUI from the timer, or need to perform lengthy processing.

Bottomline, if your `javax.swing.Timer` impacts on the GUI, keep on using that. 
Otherwise, you may want to investigate [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html).

For your specific variable delay issue, you may refer to the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#setDelay%28int%29):

> [invoking `setDelay`] does not affect the initial delay property,
>   which can be set by the `setInitialDelay` method.

Comment: setInitialDelay() seems to be what was needed. Commenting out setDelay and restart();  the program only needed setInitialDelay() instead of the setDelay. Somebody should let the publisher of that program know where he messed up.  **hehe**

Comment: @JosephKreifelsII yep saw that and upvoted Tamas' answer.